# Vue CLI dynamic import from project module

Tags: vue.js, webpack, import, es6-modules, vue-cli

I know it is possible to imports component from a bundled webpack file like this

```
import {componentA, componentB} from '../component.bundle';
```

Is it possible to achieve this same as a dynamic import, like this.

```
const url = '${window.location.origin}/assets/default/js/bundle/vue_data.bundle.js';
        this.getAxiosInstance().get(url).then(response => {
                const {Add, Edit, Filter, View} =  () => import(response.data);
        });
```

If yes, please how? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports):

> To dynamically import a module, the import keyword may be **called as a function**. When used this way, it returns a promise.

I'm assuming from your url example that your import is in the `assets` directory of your project (i.e. src > assets) and not actually on an external domain.  In that case, you don't need axios.  You would do it like this:

```js
const path = 'assets/default/js/bundle/vue_data.bundle.js';
import('@/' + path).then(module => {
  const {Add, Edit, Filter, View} = module;
});
```

You need to hardcode the `@/` portion or there will be issues, e.g. if you tried to do `import(path)` with `const path = '@/assets/default/js/bundle/vue_data.bundle.js'`

Comment: I had to resgister the '@' in the alias block of webpack to get it to work. Thank You. Legend!!!